# Hibernate 4 + Spring 3, No Inserts or Updates

Tags: spring, hibernate, open-session-in-view

In order to work around Hibernate bug [HHH-2763](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2763), I'm trying to update my app from Hibernate 3 to Hibernate 4.  It seemed to have gone smoothly until I realized that while my application can read data, it never seems to do inserts or updates.  I turned on SQL logging:  under Hibernate 3, there are inserts and updates.  Under Hibernate 4, there are no inserts and updates.

We were doing explicit flushes in Hibernate 3 by overriding the OpenSessionInViewFilter class' `closeSession` method as follows:

```
public void closeSession(Session session, SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    session.flush();
    super.closeSession(session, sessionFactory);
}
```

But in Hibernate 4, this is no longer an option because that method no longer exists.

My Hibernate 4 configuration for the Session Factory and Transaction Manager follows:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">${oracle.default_schema}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.showSql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="mappingResources">
         <list> . . . </list>
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
         <list> . . . </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Configure transaction management, enabling @Transactional annotations -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="nestedTransactionAllowed" value="true" />
</bean>
```

**(Edit)**  And here's the configuration of the `OpenSessionInViewFilter`:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

My guess is that it's not flushing and committing.  But why?

Comment: Wt about your transaction interface? You should change update property in your@transactional annotation.

Comment: For better or for worse, we explicitly specify `readOnly=true` or `readOnly=false` with each `@Transactional` annotation.  Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by "But in Hibernate 4, this is no longer an option because that method no longer exists"?
spring comes with a OpenSessionInViewFilter for hibernate 4, which is:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter
```

are you still using?

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter
```

try the new OpenSessionInViewFilter for hibernate 4

edit...

You do not have to flush the session manually, transcation manager will take care of it, as the javadoc of hibernate4 OpenSessionInViewFilter says:

> The active transaction manager will temporarily change the flush mode
>   to **FlushMode.AUTO** during a read-write transaction, with the flush
>   mode reset to FlushMode.NEVER at the end of each transaction.

you can change you log level to **TRACE**, and check the console to make sure flush mode is set to AUTO:

> ... setting flush mode to: AUTO

or can you post your save/update code fragment?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear.  You can no longer override the `closeSession` method in OpenSessionInViewFilter because it doesn't exist or isn't public.  We're using the hibernate4 version of this filter.  http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html